# Table cannot be created in mysql -Error 1064

Tags: mysql, ddl, create-table

I am trying to create a table in MySQL with the query

```
CREATE TABLE ofRosterGroups (
  rosterID              BIGINT          NOT NULL,
  rank                  TINYINT         NOT NULL,
  groupName             VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (rosterID, rank),
  INDEX ofRosterGroup_rosterid_idx (rosterID)
);
```

but seems like it is throwing error everytime I made updates too. I don't know what is going wrong with it.

Error coming up is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'rank                  TINYINT         NOT NULL,   groupName
>   VARCHAR at line 3

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://rextester.com/HYM40820).

Comment: try it in the mysql server, the same error will come

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this error reproduces in MySQL 8, it won't reproduce in MySQL 5.x - see my answer for details.

Comment: @Mureinik Yes, I have seen this error often.  Missed the MySQL 8 part +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL 8.0.2 added support for the window `rank` function, making it a [reserverd word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R).

You could escape it using backticks (`):

```
CREATE TABLE ofRosterGroups (
  rosterID              BIGINT          NOT NULL,
  `rank`                TINYINT         NOT NULL, -- Here
  groupName             VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (rosterID, `rank`), -- And here
  INDEX ofRosterGroup_rosterid_idx (rosterID)
);
```

But it may be a better idea to just use a name that isn't a reserved word, such as `rosterRank` instead of `rank`:

```
CREATE TABLE ofRosterGroups (
  rosterID              BIGINT          NOT NULL,
  rosterRank            TINYINT         NOT NULL, -- Here
  groupName             VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (rosterID, rosterRank), -- And here
  INDEX ofRosterGroup_rosterid_idx (rosterID)
);
```